# NLP synonyms for two or more word phrases in OpenNLP

Tags: ruby, nlp, synonym

Is it possible to return synonyms for two or more word phrases in OpenNLP or any other NLP library? 
eg, synonyms for

```
wind down = relax
cheer up = lighten up
```

Command line should work for me but if there is a Ruby solution, it would be even better. 
etc?